# How to improve the model's accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am definitely a new beginner of tensorflow, I tried to create a simple model, but the accuracy is super low, can someone help to figure out what is wrong?

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

train_x = [[i, j] for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)]
train_y = [[(2 * i + 3 * j) % 10] for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu", input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimzier="rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=1000)

test_x = train_x[10:60]
test_y = train_y[10:60]

model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, batch_size=100)
```

Result:

```
loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.1000
```

Comment: Questions asking to improve a model are considered off-topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404075/how-should-we-handle-machine-learning-questions-asking-for-performance-improveme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to improve your model's accuracy

- Reduce the batch size (You are using whole dataset)
- Increase the number of layers, units.
- Increase the number of epochs.
- Use unseen data to evaluate the model. (You are using 60 elements of training data)

I suggest you to read [Deep Learning with Python by Francois Chollet](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python), section 3.5 "A multiclass classification example"